# Differences between Otsu Threshold, SIS Threshold, IterativeThreshold? (Theoritically)

Tags: image-processing, comparison, theory, threshold

Tried googling the pros and cons ( advantages and disadvatnges of OTSU, SIS, and Iterative Threshold ). But was unable to find a clear answer.

To be honest, this is for a small assignment where I have to compare these three thresholding techniques and say what makes OTSU contrast among rest.

Therefore, if someone knows about these three techniques, it would be realy greatfull if can write below a bit? A huge favour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Otsu Threshold:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/b2bd54da-46c2-cb64-3577-0962d8f56554.htm

Iterative Threshold:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e01406a7-511d-ae4d-79b6-5f7eba523824.htm

SIS Threshold:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/39e861e0-e4bb-7e09-c067-6cbda5d646f3.htm

Comment: "Differences between.. Theoratically". 
a comparisson of three!